# tikz and math spacing problem: \:

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm having a problem with math mode medium spacing (\:) in conjunction with tikz:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \alpha \: \beta
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

This results in...

```
File ended while scanning use of \tikz@style@parseB. <inserted text>  \par  <*> \nonstopmode \input{junk.tex}
```

(in my "real" text, I'm getting:

```
Use of \pgfutil@xifnch doesn't match its definition. \:^ k\!\alpha_i)\vb_i
```

)

Comment: I think you are trying to include a space inside a tikzpicture but outside the math environment otherwise `\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
   \tikz \node{$\alpha \: \beta$};
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
` works.

Comment: Since the example works fine with a current TikZ version, and there's no further information (such as used versions), the question will be closed as too localized.

Answer (score 1):

The example works fine:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\typeout{<<\meaning\:>>}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \typeout{<<\meaning\:>>}
    \alpha \: \beta
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The meaning of `\:` is not changed:

```
<<macro:->\mskip \medmuskip >>
<<macro:->\mskip \medmuskip >>
```

Here the list of versions in case you are using an older version with an already fixed bug:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)
     pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
  pgfrcs.sty    2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
 ***********
```